# Looking for a definition in functional analysic of sets that generate a Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, definition

Is there a ``common'' name for a subset $K$ of a Banach space $V$ that has the following property:

For every $v\in V$ it exists $k\in K$ and a real/positive number $a$ such that $v=a k$?

Comment: absorbing sets are an example. Not sure if this is all of them https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_set